# How to hold the splash screen for a longer period?

Tags: screen, splash-screen, long-integer

I am showing a splash screen while launching the app., but I would like to dismiss it upon the completion of certain action. Is there a way to achieve that?

For example, I am launching the app which has only one screen with WKWebView in it. Now I want to dismiss the launch screen once the below navigation delegate method is fired.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!
```